# How to show tooltip for dropdown field when focus on one of the options

Tags: tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip, tooltipster

How to show tooltip for dropdown field when focus on one of the options?

i am using tooltipster.bundle.js file downloaded from http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

working fine when focus on the field,but not working when focus on one of the options.my requirment is tooltip should work when focus on one of the options and focus on the field

jsp code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="product/js/jquery/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
    });
</script>

<form:select path="product" class="tooltip" name="product" id="product" maxlength="16" title="${productListToolTip}" >
    <form:option value=""></form:option>
    <form:options items="${productList}"/>
</form:select>
```

need to show productlist in tooltip when focus on the filed and focus on one of the product.

Comment: Updated code block to remove additional spaces

Answer (score 0):

It will not work on options of a regular select form. But you could achieve it if you used the select2  library for instance, which uses actual divs which can be used for tooltips.